How to "import" into docker recovered volumes?
I backup my docker volumes that live in /var/lib/docker/volumes. Since I do that at the root (/var/lib/docker/volumes) I do not have problems to recover the data that is in the volumes but as part of a DRP I would like to recover my whole system (which is basically debian + docker)
Once I have recovered the OS, installed docker and recovered /var/lib/docker/volumes, how can I instruct docker to treat them as its volumes?
The following sequence works, but I am not sure that this is a stable approach:
root@srv ~# cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/
root@srv /v/l/d/volumes# mkdir testhelloworld
root@srv /v/l/d/volumes# mkdir testhelloworld/_data
root@srv /v/l/d/volumes# date > testhelloworld/_data/hello.txt
→ at that point I have "recovered" my raw data but the directory is not seen by docker as a volume ←
root@srv /v/l/d/volumes# docker volume create testhelloworld
testhelloworld
root@srv /v/l/d/volumes# cat testhelloworld/_data/hello.txt
2024-07-29T22:35:51 CEST
root@srv /v/l/d/volumes# docker run --rm -v testhelloworld:/mnt debian cat /mnt/hello.txt
Unable to find image 'debian:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/debian
ca4e5d672725: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:45f2e735295654f13e3be10da2a6892c708f71a71be845818f6058982761a6d3
Status: Downloaded newer image for debian:latest
2024-07-29T22:35:51 CEST

